# What is the "correct" way to achieve this postgres + redis data retrieval?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-design, redis

I have latest versions of postgres and redis being used from a nodejs server app.
The app makes thousands of PG queries to retrieve rows from a table of items, each item has a foreign key pointing to the row id of the user in the users table.
When returning a set of data, I need to get the actual username of the person that owns the item row, for every row. Each set of rows is 50 to 250 ish in count and it's possible that many of those are owned by the same person (and therefore the same username).

I am wondering which is the "correct" way to handle this.
Option one: I do a join on my PG query, or make another PG query to fetch each username.
Option two: I store the users and their ids in redis and fetch those once PG has returned the set of items.

I am leaning towards the latter, but if that is what I end up doing, there are likely more than one piece of datum I would like to associate to every user and some of which that should expire after some time. So in the end I might be doing half a dozen redisclient.set() per user and the same amount when fetching that data, is that still more efficient than using a join in my PG query?

If something needs elaborating please let me know,
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think the answer depends on the number of users that you have on your DB. If it is small, you can use redis to maintain all your users and persist them to db when they are modified. If you have nearly same amount of users with your rows, it will be better to use the first approach.

Comment: @KemalKaplan the items table is 5 billion rows ish, and the users table is 1000~ rows.
It's important that queries relating to items are as fast as they can be, because those are by far the most frequent and the ones that involve the largest data sets.

Comment: @LAZ I came here with the same exact question. I also feel like storing all user records in redis and later fetching records after getting items list would be faster as you will avoid multiple joins in the DB level. Having a "service" layer on top to fetch from redis, or add from DB if not present will obv be needed. Did you get to do one of the approaches and what did you find out? Any benchmarks you may have done?

Comment: @mavili I found out that PG is surprisingly quick. And it generally takes less time for PG to do everything itself than to have extra JS run and redis do a bunch of gets (PG's caching is pretty good!). My use of Redis is now constrained to storing the results of expensive queries that many users will request. For example, summaries for dashboards of users where a lot of variables, rows and math are involved. Another benefit of this is that you have one source of Truth for most things in your app.